# Multiple subfigures using the subfigure environment

Tags: subfloats

When I compile the attached code,I find that:
(a) The figure is not centred
(b) The subfigures overlap
(c) The captions are duplicated.
I wasn't able to include the .tikz file as I am a new user. However,I believe any other figure saved in the fig.tikz format and included in the same directory as the attached code snippet along with the matlab2tikz mfile should give a good demonstration of the problem.

```
\documentclass{report}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
    \usepackage{epsfig}
    \begin{document}
    \newlength\figureheight 
    \newlength\figurewidth 
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.2\linewidth}
        \centering
        \setlength\figureheight{4cm} 
        \setlength\figurewidth{4cm}
        \input{fig.tikz} \caption{(a) Fig 1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hspace{1cm}
    \begin{subfigure}{.2\linewidth}
        \centering      
        \setlength\figureheight{4cm} 
        \setlength\figurewidth{4cm}         
        \input{fig.tikz} \caption{(b) Fig 2}
    \end{subfigure}\\
    \vspace{1cm}    
    \begin{subfigure}{.2\linewidth}
        \centering                  
        \setlength\figureheight{4cm} 
        \setlength\figurewidth{4cm}         
        \input{fig.tikz} \caption{(c) Fig 3}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.2\linewidth}
        \centering              
        \setlength\figureheight{4cm} 
        \setlength\figurewidth{4cm}         
        \input{fig.tikz} \caption{(d) Fig 4}
    \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: `.tikz` files from matlab2tikz are just plain text files, no different from `.tex` files, simply open one in your texteditor and edit your question to include the code.

Comment: By "captions are duplicated", do you mean that the caption reads e.g. "*(a) (a) Fig 1*"? That is of course because you've written the subnumbering explicitly in the captions, but `subcaption` handles this for you, so there's no need to do that. (Also, there's no need to repeat the `\setlength`s for each figure, once right after the `\newlength`s will suffice. Unless you want to change the lengths, of course.)

Comment: You're reserving `.2\linewidth` for the width of the subfigures (about 69pt), but the subfigures are 4cm wide (about 114pt). The doubling of the labels is due to the fact that `subcaption` automatically provides them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're doing contradictory requests: you're allowing `.2\linewidth` (about 69pt) for the subfigures, while you want them 4cm wide (about 114pt).

Look at the following example (I've used `\test` instead of your `\input` just for showing the results with the `demo` option to `graphicx`)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\newcommand{\test}{\includegraphics[width=\figurewidth,height=\figureheight]{x}}

\newlength\figureheight 
\newlength\figurewidth 

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.3\linewidth}
  \centering
  \setlength\figureheight{\linewidth} 
  \setlength\figurewidth{\linewidth}
  \test \caption{Fig 1}
\end{subfigure}%
\hspace{1cm}%
\begin{subfigure}{.3\linewidth}
  \centering
  \setlength\figureheight{\linewidth}
  \setlength\figurewidth{\linewidth}
  \test \caption{Fig 2}
\end{subfigure}\\
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{subfigure}{4cm}
  \centering
  \setlength\figureheight{4cm}
  \setlength\figurewidth{4cm}
  \test \caption{Fig 3}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{4cm}
  \centering
  \setlength\figureheight{4cm}
  \setlength\figurewidth{4cm}
  \test \caption{Fig 4}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

In the first row the squares fill all the space available (`\linewidth` refers to the *current* linewidth, inside a `subcaption` environment it's what you reserved to it) and they are separated by a 1 cm space (notice the `%` comments to mask off the end of lines). In the second row the squares are 4cm wide, separated by a normal interword space.

You don't need to specify `(a)` and so on in the captions, as they are provided automatically.

[image]